# Modifying the Top Right Information panel on a Windows 2016 EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having an issue with my `Amazon EC2 Instance`. I want the information panel that appears on the top right of the instance when you access it (as displayed in the image below) to be modified. Is there a way to add lines of information from sources like one of the instance tags?

If someone has a solution to this that would be excellent. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Example of where the information panel explained above is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify it as such, it's a feature of the aws agent preinstalled on your instance. You could disable the feature in ec2config/ec2launch and then use a script to recreate the functionality with your custom data. The data displayed is accessible via http request from the instance metadata.

You could use a simple script using imagemagick, or PowerShell to create an image and set a registry key to set the new background.